# Admin Panel Errors After Opencart Update

Tags: php, error-handling, opencart

Getting the following errors after an Opencart Update:

Warning: require_once(/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/amykahn/public_html/admin/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/system/startup.php' (include_path=':/usr/local/php56/lib/php') in /home/amykahn/public_html/admin/index.php on line 17

I have looked and the file is in the correct directory with the proper permissions. I'm guessing there is a problem with my updated config.php file, but can't find anything. Total head scratcher...probably missing something small. Config.php is below:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://my123domain.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://my123domain.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://my123domain.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://my123domain.com/');

// DIR
// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '../')) . '/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '../')) . '/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', DIR_SYSTEM . 'storage/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/opencart-master/upload/catalog/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');


// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'amykahn_one');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '5up3rm4n');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'amykahn_one');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
?>
```

Any help would be massive.

Comment: what does `realpath(dirname(__FILE__)` return?  Looks like php is looking at `/system` instead of `/home/amykahn/public_html/system` which is what you intended.

Comment: @billynoah - you were correct. It was looking into the admin folder instead of the public_html folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the initial directories to the following:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/amykahn/public_html/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/amykahn/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/amykahn/public_html/image/');
```